# Shard/data allocation between nodes in Elasticsearch cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, sharding

Is it possible to know how shards/data allocated between nodes in Elasticsearch cluster? I mean which data have first node of cluster, second node and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe that's this request you want : _nodes/stats
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_monitoring_individual_nodes.html

Comment: Looks that you are right. Full command: `curl -XGET 'http://some_node_in_cluster:9200/_nodes/stats?pretty=true'`